# Firebase ID Token verification - Java NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, firebase, netbeans, firebase-admin

I try to create a simple Server in Netbeans with Firebase Admin SDK. I try to verify ID Tokens on the server, but I get an 
error

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getServiceAccountProjectId()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.then(FirebaseAuth.java:157)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.then(FirebaseAuth.java:152)
at com.google.firebase.tasks.ContinueWithCompletionListener$1.run(ContinueWithCompletionListener.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("E:\\Letöltések\\...");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setServiceAccount(serviceAccount)
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://... .firebaseio.com")
      .build();

    FirebaseApp defaultApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    System.out.println(defaultApp.getName());

    FirebaseAuth defaultAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(defaultApp);
    FirebaseDatabase defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(defaultApp);

    String idToken = getIdToken(); //"eyJhb..."

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                System.out.println("UID: " + uid);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code and error messages. Instead post the actual code and the text of the error message. You can fix this by clicking the edit link under your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.:) I'm really beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest `4.1.0` release of the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK (noted in our release notes [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java#4.1.0)). To resolve this issue, you can downgrade to version `4.0.4`. We will be pushing out a new version early this week with a fix for the issue. Sorry for any troubles!